systemd: ensure, service is started after mysql
I have a systemd path unit, which watches a config file to apply db changes if the config file changes. To ensure the path unit runs after mysql, I added these lines:
Wants=mysqld.service
After=mysqld.service
Requires=mysqld.service
ConditionPathExists=/run/mysql/mysql.sock

Despite all these, the path unit starts sometimes before mysql is running, I see these in the path status:
Condition: start condition failed at ...; 40s ago
           └─ ConditionPathExists=/run/mysql/mysql.sock was not met

And these in the corresponding service, which is doing the updates with the mysql command:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

The system is a custom linux setup with buildroot.
ExecStart of mysqld.service:
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log

mysql --version:
mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.36-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

How can I ensure mysql is running before the path unit starts watching the config file?

Which version of mysql, and, which Type= and what ExecStart= does mysqld.service have?

@grawity_u1686 I added version and ExecStart=, there is no Type=

You linked the ExecStart to a unit on GitHub, which has Type=notify – is that the same on your system, or is your version different?

You might be onto sth, we are using buildroot-2023.05, and Type=notify was added after that: https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/commit/1a9ad16ed8e5048a11d19dc411995137b154870a

Hmm, but ConditionPathExists= should prevent the service from starting at all if the path doesn't exist (yet), which means you shouldn't see condition failed and the connection error at the same time...

@TomYan This was probably because I added the conditions only to the path unit, not the service unit. Now both are conditional.

I don't have any experience with path unit, but I suppose it's similar to socket unit? Which means if the path unit isn't started at all, the corresponding service unit should never get started unless something else also pulls it (or you start it manually with systemctl). Either way, the condition path exists check doesn't make much sense anyway. Does having only Requires= and After= in both the path and service units help? (No Wants=. No ConditionPathExists=.) (But certainly, you'll need Type=notify and corresponding support, if any required, built into mysql too.)

@TomYan: It sounds like the .path unit does get started, but too early (i.e. when mysqld is still "starting") due to the lack of useful Type=, which leads to it triggering the reloader service too early as well.

@grawity_u1686 The solution is made up of three parts:

the path unit should not contain any conditions, else systemd complains about cycling dependencies, since all path units are loaded by basic.target, which is loaded by all services
the mysqld.service needs Type=notify
the service unit needs the conditions

Since your answer was the hint, which lead to the solution, if you put that as answer, I'll mark it as solved.

The solution to this problem was:

the path unit should not contain any conditions, else systemd complains about cycling dependencies, since all path units are loaded by basic.target, which is loaded by multi-user.target
look for systemd messages in dmesg
list dependencies with systemctl list-dependencies
the mysqld.service needs Type=notify
the service unit needs the conditions

    Wants=mysqld.service
    After=mysqld.service
    Requires=mysqld.service

